# OCR software which recognizes multiple complex sizes and layouts of text

Tags: ocr

Is there an OCR application which recognizes different areas of text on a page, and in different modes, e.g. outlines made out by other visual elements, or white-on-black vs black-on-white or even differences in hue - and outputs a document (say ODT or DOCX) with text placed in those areas, perhaps even arranged similarly to the arrangement on the page?

Specifically, something that in a screenshot of the following:

```
    T    HE#QUI   CK#BR
   O W   N     # F     O
  X   #  J     U M       
 P     E D#OVER  #       
 THE#LAZ Y     # D       
 O     G #     # #     #
 #     # ######   #####
```

would find both the strings "ABC" and the string "THE#QUICK#BROWN#FOX#UMPED#OVER#THE#LAZY#DOG############". And with support for other such pathologies.

License: Any; libre preferred.
Price: Any; gratis preferred.
Hardware: x86_64.
OS: Any popular one, with the order of preference being Linux, Windows, BSD, MacOS.